# Convert a .c file, that was created on a Mac, to Windows

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, macos

Is there a way to convert a .c file that was created on a Mac to be compatible with VS2010? Or am I stuck having to re-type the code by hand?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the line-endings? Or what? What exactly doesn't work about it?

Comment: If you change the line endings, it should work fine if it's not using Mac-specific function calls.  You might also have to adjust some #include paths.

Comment: Sorry, I'm referring to the EOL error you can receive, since Mac only uses '\r'. I just found an awesome feature in Notepad++ that will convert the EOL to be Windows compatible, so I'm set. For others that are curious on how to do that, in Notepad++ go to 'Edit'->'EOL Conversions'->*desired OS*

Comment: Actually, nowadays, the Mac uses Unix line endings '\n'.  However, if it's an extremely old file or created by an old program that never got around to being updated, you can still see '\r'.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [mac2dos](http://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/software/mac2dos/mac2dos.html).